# How do i use an encrypted database on flutter in the background in iOS reliably?

Tags: ios, database, flutter, encryption, hive

How do i encrypt a database in flutter and use it on ios?

Initial efforts were with hive with the key flutter_secure_storage. This works fine on Android, but on iOS we seem to run into problems with IOS accessibility. the default is particularly bad, and "always" is not available through the plugin and has been marked deprecated and/or "not recommended" ; see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/restricting_keychain_item_accessibility

and: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

If db is protected bc device is locked then it  appears to return contains=false, read=null the same as if it were never written, so then making a new key and using   it can corrupt/delete the entire db

Some ideas

1. check app resumed to see if background access
2. wirte and read a dummy value and see if it is the same
3. save into sharedprefs initializedHive true/false or similar
4. check cupertinoIsProtected, but that seems to require code in develop not released to pub.dev for flutter_secure_storage

Tried readAll , read, contains, was hoping for an exception rather than null/empty from flutter_secure_storage
see: https://github.com/neiljaywarner/flutter_background_geolocation/commit/0a55e883e68edab3cec0cfd18bec22466b6cf0b3#diff-86917493a1c5b1988760f51b20bbac6281d105e6d0699e1d97b1ee1cb30db4b4